# Is `sizeof(some_vector[0])` valid?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, sizeof

For a generic way to find the size of elements in a vector, is this valid:

```
std::vector<float> some_vector;
int size = sizeof(some_vector[0]);
```

Or could this lead to problems, because some_vector[0] could be empty?

*I guess this evaluated during compile time anyway, but is it according to the standard?*

Comment: That is perfectly fine, so is `sizeof(*static_cast<float*>(0))`;

Comment: Bear in mind that what is returned by `v[0]` may not be the same type as the `T` in `std::vector<T> v;`. For instance, consider the proxy type returned by `vector<bool>`.

Answer (score 2):

The `sizeof` operator is used with unevaluated expressions. So you can use this expression to determine the size of the element of a vector.

From the C++ Standard (5.3.3 Sizeof)

> 1 The sizeof operator yields the number of bytes in the object
>   representation of its operand. The operand is either an expression,
>   which is an unevaluated operand (Clause 5), or a parenthesized
>   type-id. The sizeof operator shall not be applied to an expression
>   that has function or incomplete type, to an enumeration type whose
>   underlying type is not ﬁxed before all its enumerators have been
>   declared, to the parenthesized name of such types, or to a glvalue
>   that designates a bit-ﬁeld. sizeof(char), sizeof(signed char) and
>   sizeof(unsigned char) are 1. The result of sizeof applied to any other
>   fundamental type (3.9.1) is implementation-deﬁned. [Note: in
>   particular, sizeof(bool), sizeof(char16_t), sizeof(char32_t), and
>   sizeof(wchar_t) are implementation-deﬁned.75 —end note] [Note: See 1.7
>   for the deﬁnition of byte and 3.9 for the deﬁnition of object
>   representation. —end note]